# How do I prevent my sidekiq workers from overwhelming its database connection limit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Right now my DigitalOcean managed database backend connection limit is 22. Here are my `sidekiq.yml` and `database.yml` configurations:

```
# config/sidekiq.yml

development:
  :concurrency: 18
production:
  :concurrency: 18
```

.

```
# config/database.yml

default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 18
```

I have a bunch or workers that interact with the database whenever I kick off a scheduled task. Since we're planning on allowing this scheduled task to kick off multiple times at the same time, we're running into a lot of connection database pool errors. So now I'm trying to figure out the best way to optimize this process or find another service that may be better for us.

For testing purposes, I created a sidekiq worker that looks like this:

```
class MySampleWorker
    include Sidekiq::Worker
    sidekiq_options queue: Rails.env.to_sym
    
    def perform
        User.first
    end
end
```

If I call this sidekiq worker 20 times simultaneously, everything runs just smoothly. But if I call it 50 times simultaneously, then I get about 3-5 failed workers that ends up being retried.

My question is -- how would I scale something like this? In my case, I'm going to have to call the same workers multiple times, more and more as the demand grows, and that's obviously going to result in several failed workers. In some cases, these workers may take 5-10 minutes each - they're essentially running health check commands on remote systems and waiting on outputs in order to complete the worker.

Scaling in this manner seems like it would be disastrous. Rather than the workers failing, is there any way to just simply have them queued up and run when there's available space, as opposed to failing? If I understand the way this works, shouldn't `database.yml` be limiting the connection at 18 and, thus, it should never actually be trying to access the postgresql database beyond 18 connections at a time while the postgresql database has a connection limit of 22? I would think I should expect to see activerecord database connection timeout errors *before* I see any issues with postgresql database connection issues.

Here's the error I receive when one of the workers fail now:

```
2020-06-18T15:05:16.536Z pid=1152049 tid=gofhou0qp WARN: PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections

2020-06-18T15:05:16.536Z pid=1152049 tid=gofhou0qp WARN: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/pg-1.2.3/lib/pg.rb:58:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/pg-1.2.3/lib/pg.rb:58:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/pg-1.2.3/lib/pg.rb:58:in `connect'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activerecord-5.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:692:in `connect'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activerecord-5.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:223:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activerecord-5.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:48:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activerecord-5.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:48:in `postgresql_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activerecord-5.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:830:in `new_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activerecord-5.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:874:in `checkout_new_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activerecord-5.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:853:in `try_to_checkout_new_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activerecord-5.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:814:in `acquire_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activerecord-5.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:538:in `checkout'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activerecord-5.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:382:in `connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activerecord-5.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:1033:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activerecord-5.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:118:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activerecord-5.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:90:in `connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activerecord-5.2.4/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:76:in `connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activerecord-5.2.4/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:934:in `build_arel'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activerecord-5.2.4/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:900:in `arel'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activerecord-5.2.4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:560:in `block in exec_queries'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activerecord-5.2.4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:584:in `skip_query_cache_if_necessary'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activerecord-5.2.4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:547:in `exec_queries'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activerecord-5.2.4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:422:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activerecord-5.2.4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:200:in `records'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/bullet-6.1.0/lib/bullet/active_record52.rb:46:in `records'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activerecord-5.2.4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:195:in `to_ary'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activerecord-5.2.4/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:532:in `find_nth_with_limit'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activerecord-5.2.4/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:517:in `find_nth'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activerecord-5.2.4/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:125:in `first'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activerecord-5.2.4/lib/active_record/querying.rb:5:in `first'
/var/www/test-dev/app/workers/my_sample_worker.rb:12:in `perform'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:196:in `execute_job'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:164:in `block (2 levels) in process'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:133:in `invoke'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:163:in `block in process'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:136:in `block (6 levels) in dispatch'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/job_retry.rb:111:in `local'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:135:in `block (5 levels) in dispatch'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/rails.rb:43:in `block in call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:87:in `wrap'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/reloader.rb:73:in `block in wrap'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:87:in `wrap'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/reloader.rb:72:in `wrap'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/rails.rb:42:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:131:in `block (4 levels) in dispatch'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:257:in `stats'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:126:in `block (3 levels) in dispatch'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/job_logger.rb:13:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:125:in `block (2 levels) in dispatch'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/job_retry.rb:78:in `global'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:124:in `block in dispatch'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/logger.rb:10:in `with'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/job_logger.rb:33:in `prepare'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:123:in `dispatch'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:162:in `process'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:78:in `process_one'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:68:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/util.rb:15:in `watchdog'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/util.rb:24:in `block in safe_thread'
```

Here's my Puma config:

```
threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 }
threads threads_count, threads_count

port        ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }

environment ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") { "development" }
```

Comment: My database pool and sidekiq concurrency is set to 18 but the database max connection is set to 22. If my sidekiq workers are set to make 50 connections to the database, shouldn't it have an error with activerecord instead of postgresql since the connection to postgresql should be limited by the database.yml file? or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Are you using Puma or Unicorn as the server?

Comment: I'm using Puma as the server

Comment: I had this very issue, and memory tells me that it's because the pool count isn't as simple as 18. It's dependant on the puma config as well - the number of puma threads and workers you have. Can you post your puma config as well? I assume you have only one app server running?

Comment: Gotcha. My puma config is set to 5 threads since the environment variable RAILS_MAX_THREADS isn't set. Updated the post containing that config information. Only one single puma web server is running.

Comment: And just to be clear - is that the whole puma config? There is just a single worker with 5 threads?

Comment: Yep that's correct. Everything else in the config are commented out. The config is default as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you scale up, you should just get a queue of jobs for workers to work on - if your concurrency is correctly set. Not failed jobs - your expectation there is correct.

However, the expectation that setting the database pool to 18 is maybe wrong. And, certainly only applies within each application server (do you have multiple?)

But this will depend on how you have Puma configured, post that config.

And see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/concurrency-and-database-connections for a good description of how the pool should be shared between workers and multiple application servers. And, https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server for best practise on setting worker and thread size.

Comment: I migrated off of Sidekiq (to Shoryuken) so I don't have my config to hand anymore, but those bogs helped me. If you do get a definitive answer please post it in here? You might actually require some experimentation to get the best result - not each worker will always use a connection, so you can probably push the edges a bit if you want max worker throughput.

Comment: Thanks so much Tom! After playing around with Digital Ocean's managed database instance, I managed to add a connection pool (which I thought was already configured) and this seems to help significantly. Whereas before I couldn't run 20 sidekiq jobs simultaneously, it seems that I can run thousands with no problem now. Will continue to experiment and update if I have anything else that I can contribute. Thanks for your help!